Updating GDAL and PROJ - how to test efficiently
I am in the process of updating GDAL and PROJ in my program. I am currently using GDAL 2.3.0 with PROJ 5.0.1 , and I would like to update to the most recent version of the libraries. However, those libraries have seen some major updates and I would like to be able to do extensive testing to check the results of coordinate system transformation with my current implementation, and the new implementation, to search for important discrepancies and spot abnormal behaviors.
What would be your approach to this problem? My initial thought was to generate a list of all possible transformations that make sense for each country in the world and test it in both implementations and compare the results, but I am not even sure how to go on with the creation of such list.
Or programmatically, for each coordinate system, retrieve its bounding box, search for coordinate system that overlaps this bounding box and test the transformation.
Any clever ideas or link to available resources?

surely your existing tests will pick up any regression?

Old Proj used WGS84 as a pivot CRS (input_crs->WGS84->output_crs).  New Proj tries to avoid pivot (input_crs->output_crs) https://proj.org/en/stable/usage/transformation.html.
It is sure that new Proj often does not give same results than the old version. The results from the new Proj should be more accurate.
